# Unit/Instrumentation tests Android Gradle. Instrumentation tests won't run

Tags: android, testing, instrumentation

I have Tests set up in an Android project in Android Studio. I have a Unit test class with tests and an Instrumentation test class with tests. When I run gradlew connectedAndroidTest the unit tests run fine but the instrumentation tests are not run.

Here is my project structure

root
  - app
    - src
      - androidTest
        - java
          - packagename
            - UnitTest class
            - InstrumentationTest class

The unit test class extends TestCase. The instrumentation test class extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

An example test in the instrumentation test class is

```
public void testJSONReturnsString() {

    String json = JSON.getJSonFeed(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),     "http://foo.bar");
    assertNotNull(json);
}
```

In my build.gradle I have 
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"

in the defaultConfig section

Does anyone know why the Instrumentation test class wouldn't run?

Comment: What if you remove the `testInstrumentationRunner` part from your `build.gradle`? You can also take a look at [my app on github](https://github.com/nhaarman/DashPinkpop) as an example, where I'm using both unit and instrumentation tests. Also, I'm using `gradlew connectedCheck`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it was because I didn't have a default constructor in my instrumentation class!